# Laptop no longer works on battery power (HP G72)

Tags: laptop, bios, battery, charging

I have an old hp laptop (2009?) that one day stopped working on battery power. I'm not sure if the problem is that the laptop will not charge the battery or if the laptop will not make use of the battery (or both). Apparently this is a known problem with this model, but none of the online fixes I found worked.

It works when plugged in and the battery monitor reports that it is charging and at 11% however that 11% is unchanging (over weeks) and as soon as I unplug it, it shuts off. I originally thought it was a battery problem so I purchased a new battery. The new battery worked, but it was not charged by the pc and eventually died at which point I purchased another new battery with the same result. I thought it might be the adapter, so I bought a new adapter, but that also had no effect.

Right now I have replaced the ram (4G to 8G) and the harddrive (500G to 1T) and dual boot arch and windows 7. I'm considering upgrading the bios, but before needlessly wasting time on something like that and potentially jacking up this computer, I wanted to know what you think.

Gnome does not indicate if it is charging or not, it just reads: estimating.

Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but as indicated in my post I have reason to believe that isn't the issue.

Comment: Have you bought the correct charger? One that has the correct power rating?